# Track Docker-for-mac CLI program execution output to find run invocation

Tags: docker, zsh

I am using Zsh + Docker-for-mac on my work MacBook.

upon startup of a new shell session, I receive the following output from presumably the docker for mac CLI:

`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I am having a hard time understanding where this initial command to the docker CLI is being initiated from. I have checked all RC files; bash, zsh etc. but cannot find any relevant command invoking to docker CLI.

Is there a way to trace commands executed from RC scripts and the location of those commands to determine where this startup command is defined?

Comment: Try to see the Docker Desktop startup on login under Docker -> Preferences

Comment: @Saurabh you mean the preferences of the docker-for-mac application? When the app is OFF the docker CLI is still starting and running some command, which is where the error comes from cause it cannot connect to the docker daemon

Comment: Command+spacebar search the Docker app and run the Docker app on mac, once it's up, you should be able to execute commnads for example `docker ps`. You can check by docker pid as well at - /var/run/docker.pid

Comment: @Saurabh I think you miss-understand my issue. I have no problem getting the docker daemon running and executing commands against it.

What I am saying is, if the daemon is NOT running, when I open a new terminal session I am getting the above error. Meaning there is a command somewhere trying to be run against the daemon, which isnt running. I am trying to understand where this command is coming from that generates this error output

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your query and this is weird! If you are able to run commands it implies that sock file is accessible to the user with which commands are being issued. I tried to play on my mac by changing docker daemon config, but couldn't reproduce.
--
Couple of things which you can take a look is checking, DOCKER_HOST env variable. Make sure when your zsh profile loads, it can access sock file: /var/run/docker.sock. Check the symlink to sock file if it's under your user and is part of docker group.
--
That's all I have for now.